# MongoDB unset removes everything in child

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, unset

I have a db structure like this:

```
   { "_id" : ObjectId("5fd48e12e5e0fd174c1a7260"), 
     "races" : { 
               "example1" : { "date" : "12/18/2020", "status" : "pending" }, 
               "example2" : { "date" : "12/18/2020", "status" : "domestic" } 
           }
```

and I am attempting to just remove `example 1` by using the following block of code(javascript):

```
  self.db  =  client.db("authinfo");
  self.collection = self.db.collection("users");

this.delete_both_races = function (user1) {

    self.collection.updateOne({user:user1} ,{$unset:{races:"example1"}} ,function(error,result){});
```

same thing happens when running the following command in the mongo.exe command line program:

```
db.users.updateOne({user:"anything"} , {$unset:{races:"example1"}})
```

I get the result of(remaining elements after unsetting) :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fd48e12e5e0fd174c1a7260") }
```

desired result :

```
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5fd48e12e5e0fd174c1a7260"), 
    "races" : { 
                   "example2" : { "date" : "12/18/2020", "status" : "domestic" } 
               }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should unset `races.example1` instead of `races`.

From [MongoDB document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/),

> The specified value in the $unset expression (i.e. "") does not impact the operation.
>
> To specify a  in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jE4HE4hJhEA)

Comment: Clean And  Easy to understand!! Thanks (upvote)